# Estilos en text field

Tags: flutter, dart

Quiero pasar de esto
[image: Imagen 1]

a esto
[image: Imagen 2]

Además el ícono que puse no se adapta al tamaño que le pongo: sale mucho más grande.
Quisiera saber cómo puedo solucionarlo.

```
TextField(
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Image.asset(
        'assets/grupo33697.png',
        width: 13.9,
      ),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 50),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              const Radius.circular(15))),
      hintText: 'Escribe tu usuario',
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(52, 52, 52, 1))),
),
```

Comment: En lugar de hintText, creo que puedes usar la propiedad labelText para que el texto cambie de posición según si se ha pulsado o no el TextField, para lo otro, puedes buscar un poco por google o leer la doc. Pero puede probar con prefixIconConstraints

Comment: Intente con labelText pero el resultado es completamente diferente al que espero, igual muchas gracias